# How to transform this img code like this in php (regex pattern)

Tags: php, html, regex, youtube

This is my HTML code:

```
<img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/ErIRt52MOkE/0.jpg" class="mceItem" alt="ErIRt52MOkE"/>
```

And I want transform this code like this:

```
<iframe title="YouTube video player" width="640" height="390" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/ErIRt52MOkE" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

This my pattern: (`Message: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Unknown modifier 'v'`)

```
<img(?=[^>]+?class="mceItem")(?=[^>]+?alt="[\w]+?")[^>]+?img.youtube.com/vi/([\w]+?)/0.jpg[^>]*?/>
```

Comment: Yes, that's possible. There are other questions like this. Use the search function to find other tips. Then update your question with attempts you made, so it gets a little less broad or a plain coding inquiry.

Comment: Well, escape your [delimiters](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php). Or use e.g. `#` instead of `/`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
<?php
  preg_match_all('%youtube\.com\/vi\/([^\/]+)%','<img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/ErIRt52MOkE/0.jpg" class="mceItem" alt="ErIRt52MOkE"/>',$matches);

  print_r($matches);

  $outputStr = '<iframe title="YouTube video player" width="640" height="390" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$matches[1][0].'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';

  echo $outputStr;
?>
```